# Filter Productcollection by sku

Tags: collections, filter, magento2

I tried to get all products with suitable skus in Magento 2.

What i did:

```
$currentSku =  $_product->getSku();

$currentSku = substr($currentSku, 0, 3);

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $productCollection */
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
$productCollection->addFieldToFilter('sku', array('like' => ''.$currentSku.' %'));
/** Apply filters here */
$productCollection->load();
```

The collection is always empty but there are suitable products.

I tried to filter the collection by name and this worked.

Comment: $productCollection->addFieldToFilter('sku', array('like' => ''.$currentSku.' %'));  Your '' will terrminate in-correctly.  try array('like' => "'.$currentSku.' %"));

Comment: Thanks but i guess it worked already before, i am just not able to output some information. i tried foreach($collection as $item) {$item->getName(); } but without any result.

Comment: $productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
            ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('like'=>$skuPart.'%'));

Comment: Dude it's Magento 2, this code is for Mage1

Comment: your absolutely right, my appologies: I copied from the wrong test env.  Your question code works for me when i delete the space before % in the filter field

Comment: i debugged the collection using xdebug and i gets the right items, but i can't output the items name in foreach

Comment: try adding ->addAttributeToSelect('Name') or ->addAttributeToSelect('*')

Comment: Yeah this did it for me thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

There is a space after your SKU. 
Change it to

```
$productCollection->addFieldToFilter('sku', array('like' => ''.$currentSku.'%'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        ....
    ) {
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        ...
    }

    public function getProducts($currentSku)
    {
        /** @var $collection \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection */
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => 1))
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('like' => $currentSku.'%'))
                    ->addStoreFilter()
                    ->load();
        return $collection;
    }
```